# The proper implementation and using of custom char streams with ANTLR >= 4.7

Tags: java, stream, antlr4

In ANTLR 4.6 and earlier the following code works fine:

```
String code = readFile(args[0]);
ANTLRCustomStream codeStream = new ANTLRCustomStream(code);
MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer(codeStream);
```

I use a [CaseInsensitiveInputStream.java](https://gist.github.com/sharwell/9424666) for char case ignoring by way of `ANTLRCustomStream`.

But how can I use case insensitive input stream in ANTLR of version 4.7 and later? `ANTLRInputStream` is deprecated and I don't want to use it.

```
CharStream codeStream = CharStreams.fromFileName(args[0]);
// customCharStream here
MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer(customCharStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the CharStreams interface does not allow to use custom streams. You have to create your custom stream just like before (via `new CaseInsensitiveInputStream(...)`). The CharStreams interfaces is only of limited use (to create optimized streams for standard cases).

Btw. I'd rather recommend to use the typical `A: [aA]; B: [bB]; ..` approach to implement case insensitivity. That lowercasing trick is just a hack that doesn't work for full Unicode input (e.g. some uppercass letters can have multiple lower case variants). Uppercasing however also does not help here (e.g. in german uppercasing `Straße` becomes `STRASSE`).

In general it's very tricky to implement a truly case insensitive parsing for full Unicode input, as it requires to case fold both input and grammar tokens to be able to compare them.

Comment: Case insensitive fragments are not appropriate due to the following reasons:

1. They are slower than ordinary tokens (abc: 'abc'), see @jim-idle [comment on Ignore case new syntax issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1002#issuecomment-141955368).

2. In most cases transformation of "Straße" won't be a problem because of "messaging and other `getText()` methods return data from the original input string" (see @sam-harwell [comment here](https://gist.github.com/sharwell/9424666#gistcomment-1186748)). And "Straße" can not be a keyword (in general this is a string literal).

Comment: You seem to work on that case insensitivity problem for quite some time already :-) For the `Straße` example: all I wanna show with that is the problem with char count changes due to lower or upper casing, which makes the case insensitive comparison by lower casing so unreliable. That might work for ANSI input, but not full Unicode. What you would really need is case folding (and normalization while we are on it) here.